# Organic Group Setup

Tags: organic-groups

Following the recommendation of the stack drupaler i have been looking into OG for new website, although i am a little confuse whether or not it s the way to go. 
Here is what i need to be available:

1. User created group: Each user can create it s own group and get "administrator privileges on it"
2. Limited number of user can then join this group
3. The Group as it s own "blog page"

Is the OG the way to go for this or should i look into other module or at worst built one custom for my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OG will do exactly this right out of the box. Just add the [Organic Groups join limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_limit) module to get your Join Limit. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> This module allows to set a join limit on a specific group.

Answer (score 2):

OG is will work perfectly for you.
1. User created group: in permissions give the members the permission to create group or
   or create a group with members having the permission to create the group( can also use role to create new role for group creator).
2. as suggested use above use group limit to limit the group size http://drupal.org/project/og_limit  .
3.just enable the blog module and in content type :blog select  group content.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure the group settings to require approval to join the group if you want to leave the limit up to the group's owner/admins.

Comment: Can you expand a little on how to configure this?

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure which version you're using, but in Drupal 6, when you either create the group node itself (eg: something like yoursite.com/node/add/group) or edit this node, there is a setting called Membership Requests. It has the following 4 options, which are only somewhat self-explanatory IMO. 
 
1.) Open - membership requests are accepted immediately.  
2.) Moderated - membership requests must be approved by a group admin.  
3.) Invite only - members must be invited by an admin then accept.  
4.) Closed - membership is exclusively managed by an admin.